# "I will see the turn." What does it mean in gambling?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

There is a gambling scene in the movie *Michael Clayton*. Several gamblers play an unspecified game.

> Gambler A: **I'll see the turn**. (lays some chips on the table)
>
> Gambler B: Check.
>
> Gambler C: Half the pot. 200.
>
> Dealer: 200 to go.

What does *I will see the turn* mean here? Does it mean that person is calling/raising?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like they're playing [Texas Hold 'em](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_hold_%27em) (or some other game with community cards):

> Texas hold 'em (also known as Texas holdem, hold 'em, and holdem) is a variation of the card game of poker. Two cards, known as the hole cards, are dealt face down to each player, and then five community cards are dealt face up in three stages. The stages consist of a series of three cards ("the flop"), later an additional single card ("the turn" or "fourth street"), and a final card ("the river" or "fifth street").

If he wants to see the turn, then he wants to see the fourth card. That's what it means. However, what he's implying is unclear. It could be a check, call, or raise. Judging from the action, my best guess is that he's signaling a call. The sequencing seems strange to me though.

Comment: Yep.  It's gambling jargon specific to this particular version of poker.  I agree the language is a little odd, it might be the screenwriter was not familiar with how the game works.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Glad someone agrees.

Comment: I'm not a poker player, but I think if you're the first person to bet then you either *check* or *raise*.  To *see* the bet means the same as to *call* the bet, meaning to add whatever amount of money is needed to match the current bet.  You can't *see* a bet if there is no bet.

Comment: That being said, if I recall the movie correctly this scene is not important.  It establishes the main character (Michael Clayton) is a gambler, possibly one with debts.  His main job is as a lawyer (of sorts), and the rest of the movie revolves around that, as well as his relationships with his family.